# Efficient join between variable columns

Tags: mysql

I would like to join two tables and get the result described below, in an efficient way.

Sadly I cannot change the table structure.

The two tables I'd like to join look like this:

`Projects`

```
┌─────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ proj_id │ set1 │ get1 │ set2 │ get2 │ set3 │ get3 │ set4 │ get4 │
├─────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│  154777 │   10 │   14 │   28 │   42 │   10 │   11 │   19 │   22 │
│  175848 │   13 │   14 │   55 │   41 │   11 │   10 │   19 │   12 │
│  149999 │   16 │   13 │   22 │   22 │   10 │   91 │   12 │   14 │
│  208884 │   17 │   14 │   21 │   23 │   14 │   18 │   29 │   25 │
└─────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

and

`ProjCDS`

```
┌────────┬────────┐
│ projid │ setCDS │
├────────┼────────┤
│ 149999 │      1 │
│ 149999 │      3 │
│ 149999 │      4 │
│ 154777 │      1 │
│ 154777 │      2 │
│ 154777 │      3 │
│ 154777 │      4 │
│ 175848 │      1 │
│ 208884 │      2 │
│ 208884 │      4 │
└────────┴────────┘
```

The desired select result should output two columns:

```
┌───┬─────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ 1 │  149999 │        16,13,10,91,12,14 │
│ 2 │  154777 │  10,14,28,42,10,11,19,22 │
│ 3 │  175848 │                    13,14 │
│ 4 │  208884 │              17,14,29,25 │
└───┴─────────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

I started by grouping the values of the `ProjCDS` table:

```
SELECT projid, concat('set',GROUP_CONCAT(setCDS SEPARATOR ',set')) FF
FROM ProjCDS
GROUP BY projid
```

And got this:

```
┌────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ 149999 │  set1,set3,set4      │
│ 154777 │  set1,set2,set3,set4 │
│ 175848 │  set1                │
│ 208884 │  set2,set4           │
└────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

I was going to add more but I think I'm on the wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

Unpivot `Projects` "by hands":

```sql
WITH 
cte AS 
(
SELECT proj_id, 1 AS num, 1 AS type, set1 AS values
UNION ALL
SELECT proj_id, 1 AS num, 2 AS type, get1 AS values
UNION ALL
-- ...
SELECT proj_id, 4 AS num, 1 AS type, set4 AS values
UNION ALL
SELECT proj_id, 4 AS num, 2 AS type, get4 AS values
)
```

then join, group and concat with proper ordering.